# How expand Binomial[n, k] for k >= 6?

Tags: combinatorics

[`Binomial[n, k]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binomial.html) is converted to a polynomial only for `k` less than 6.

```
Table[Binomial[n, k], {k, 1, 8}]
(* {n,
1/2 (-1 + n) n,
1/6 (-2 + n) (-1 + n) n,
1/24 (-3 + n) (-2 + n) (-1 + n) n,
1/120 (-4 + n) (-3 + n) (-2 + n) (-1 + n) n,
Binomial[n, 6],
Binomial[n, 7],
Binomial[n, 8]} *)
```

For `k` greater or equal 6 is an output only copy of [`Binomial[n, k]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binomial.html). Why?
It's possible change this boundary? (but I not accept a solution like [`Product[...]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product.html))

Comment: Use `FunctionExpand[]`.

Comment: Yes, good idea! Thank you.

Comment: Okay, can you answer your question now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution of my problem is

```
FunctionExpand[Table[Binomial[n, k], {k, 1, 8}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also define your own binomial coefficient function, e.g.

```
bn[n_, k_] := Fold[(n - #2 + 1) #1/#2 &, 1, Range[k]]
```

so,

```
Grid[{HoldForm[Binomial[n, #]], bn[n, #]} & /@ Range[0, 8], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]