# Binomial Expansion on Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Why when I typed `Expand[Binomial[m-1,6]]`, it gives me `Binomial[-1 + m, 6]` instead of `1/720 (m-6)(m-5)(m-4)(m-3)(m-2)(m-1)` ? I want my output to be like the second one, is there any other command that I need to use? Thank you.

Comment: Try `Binomial[m - 1, 6] // FunctionExpand`.

Comment: This question already has answers here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85841/how-expand-binomialn-k-for-k-6/85843#85843

Comment: Thank you so much!!!